# How to deploy a Vue.JS MPA (Multi Page Application)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs-routing

I created a multipage application using vue.js with vue.config.js method i developed it with no problems i created a production build i can access home page however i cannot access other pages like about us, portfolio etc.

What could be the issue?? and how to solve it? is it about the .htacess?

here is my vue.config.js code

```
module.exports = {
    pages: {
      index: {
        entry: './src/pages/Home/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'Welcome to Appclust',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
      },
      about:{
        entry: './src/pages/About/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'About us',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'about']
      },
      portfolio:{
        entry: './src/pages/Portfolio/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'Portfolio',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'portfolio']
      },
      testimonials:{
        entry: './src/pages/Testimonials/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'Testimonials',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'testimonials ']
      },
      careers:{
        entry: './src/pages/Careers/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'Careers',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'careers']
      },
      contact:{
        entry: './src/pages/Contact/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'Contact',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'contact']
      }
    }
  }
```

this is my file structure
[image]

production files

[image]

Comment: for tasks like multipages i would suggest to use nuxt instead of vue CLI

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable `mode:history` for pretty URL in vue-router without hashbang
2. since your project is SPA from beginning, the Crawler/server doesn't recognize your routes after new visit/refresh of the route (because `/about` missing index.html as it expected.)
3. Yes you can set redirect rules in the `.htaccess` for the missing routes.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# otherwise use history router
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

4. Optional: If you wished to generate prerendered static HTML files for each routes, [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) is a good addition into your project build. If you wished to build MPA from beginning, go NUXT.

Comment: will .htaccess do the job?

Comment: Yes it should do the job. Solved previously with AngularJS with Shared Hosting

Comment: Should i copy paste the same thing?? i mean htaccess you gave?? or should i do some modifications?? i copy pasted the same thing but no matter what page i click it goes to home or index page. 

i deleted this line
 "# otherwise use history router
RewriteRule ^ /index.html" then i got errors when i tried to navigate to other pages

Comment: @BeingMR.G likely some changes, you may refer more here about History mode with Vue: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: thank you i got it fixed. Do you know how to add meta tags in MPA ?? since i am not using Nuxt i have no clue how to add meta description on each pages

Comment: you may use vue-meta for the dynamic keywords, description and  title etc. It's compatible with NUXT and Vue as well. And please kindly green tick the answer if resolved :) Cheers